# pthreads locking scheme to allow concurrent reads of a shared data structure

Tags: concurrency, pthreads, mutex

Let's say you have some code that both reads and writes to a data structure.  If you have multiple threads executing this code (and sharing the data structure), is there some arrangement that would achieve the following:

1. Allow 2 or more concurrent reads, with no writes
2. Disallow 2 or more writes
3. Disallow 1 or more reads concurrently with 1 or more writes

A single mutex that is locked during any read and any write achieves goals 2 and 3, but fails to achieve goal 1.  Is there some solution that achieves all three goals?

Assume that it is not possible to devise a scheme where different sub-sections of the data structure can be protected with different mutexes.

My clunkly approach to this is:

1. Have one mutex per thread, and each thread locks its own mutex when it needs to read.
2. Have one additional 'global' mutex.  When any thread wants to write, it first locks this global mutex.  Then it goes through a loop of pthread_mutex_trylock() on all of the thread-specific mutexes until it has locked them all, then performs the write, then unlocks them all.  Finally, it unlocks the global mutex.

This approach seems to be likely not very efficient, however.

Thanks in advance,

Henry

Comment: Pthreads supports a `pthread_rwlock_t` that is supposed to do what you want: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_destroy.html.  I have no experience using them.

Answer (score 2):

Pthreads includes reader-writer locks that have this behaviour.  You initialise them in an analagous way to mutexes - either statically:

```
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;
```

or dynamically with `pthread_rwlock_init()`.

To lock for reading (shared) you use `pthread_rwlock_rdlock()`, and to lock for writing (exclusive) you use `pthread_rwlock_wrlock()`.  There are also "trylock" and "timedlock" variations of these.

---

You can, of course, also build such a lock from pthreads mutex and condition variables.  For example, you could implement the reader-side lock as:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
readers++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

The writer-side lock is:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (readers > 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&mutex, &cond);
```

The reader-side unlock is:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
if (--readers == 0)
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

And the writer-side unlock is:

```
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

(This is just for interest's sake - you are better off using the built-in reader-writer locks, because those can be implemented directly using architecture-specific code which may well be more efficient than using the other pthreads primitives).

Note also that in a real implementation you would want to consider the case of `readers` overflowing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @caf.  That is an elegant solution.  If I understand your mutex / cond formulation, in the `while (readers > 0) pthread_cond_wait(&mutex, &cond)` loop, `readers` may both increase and decrease, so the writer-side lock is at the mercy of all of the other threads just happening to be outside of the reading section at the same time.

Comment: @HenryBigelow: Yes, readers effectively get priority over writers.  This is true of the built-in pthreads rwlocks as well, because they guarantee that read locks are recursive - that is, you can safely re-lock a read lock you already hold.  If you had later-arriving readers wait for writers, then this would deadlock (unless you gave special dispensation to the recursive case, which would require keeping track of every read lock held by every thread, which requires unbounded space).